# How to send key combination / Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: mobile, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, honeywell

I´ve got a windows mobile 6.5 device (Honeywell) in combination with SOTI. What I need to implement is, that, if the device has a akku status <10 percent, it should shutdown. That is the part I can do with SOTI.

Before this shutdown I need to send the F12-key five times. How can I realize that? I know that there a virtual key-codes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx) but I don´t know, how to trigger them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453245.aspx) function

```
    keybd_event( VK_F12, 0, 0, 0 );
    keybd_event( VK_F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
```

To use that from .NET see [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.keybd_event)

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    ...
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
    
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void keybd_event
    (
      byte bVk,
      byte bScan,
      int dwFlags,
      int dwExtraInfo
    );
```

Always use two calls with the same key value, one for key dwon and one with KEYEVENTF_KEYUP.

The bScan for the scan code can normally be 0 or you need to lookup the PS/2 keyboard scan codes for the key you send.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Do I need to use frameworks for that? Or can I just copy paste it to a script file?

Comment: It depends: if C/C++ no additional work needed; if .NET you need to pinvoke that keybd_event